# Trying to learn polymer by modifying polymer tutorial

Tags: polymer

I was able to install and run the polymer 'unquote' tutorial successfully.

Now I want to modify it, but I can't figure out how. Specifically, the post-cards are lined up vertically in one column. I would like to line them up in different ways. For example horizontally and/or in multiple columns.

There is a hint in the tutorial: 
http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/step-2.html
"The layout horizontal center attributes are Polymer shorthand to create a flexbox layout."

So I looked at flexbox documentation at css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Then I changed the attributes from 'layout horizontal center'
to 'layout vertical center', 'layout horizontal left', ...

Nothing changed. The post-cards always line up vertically in one column. Can somebody steer me in the right direction? The answer could be as simple as a link to the documentation that I can't find.

Erwan, I must be missing something obvious. I can't figure out how to incorporate your idea into this code in post-list.html.

```
<div layout vertical center> 
    <template repeat="{{post in posts}}"> 
        <post-card favorite="{{post.favorite}}" on-favorite-tap="{{handleFavorite}}" hidden?="{{show == 'favorites' && !post.favorite}}"> 
            <img src="{{post.avatar}}" width="70" height="70"> 
            <h2>{{post.username}}</h2> 
            <p>{{post.text}}</p> 
        </post-card> 
    </template> 
</div>
```

I am a dummy.

Comment: [Layout docs of Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html#horizontal-and-vertical-layout)

Comment: Just as a personal note, I find that specifying layout attributes is no better than inline style in HTML, it's unsemantic. You can achieve the same result by using flexbox through CSS.

Comment: thanks, that is helpful, both the link and the personal note.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to update the enclosing layout element's attributes.

For example, in my app, I have a core-card with paper-item(s) in it, stacked vertically. The attributes of the core-card contains : *vertical layout*. If I change the attributes to *horizontal layout*, the items are stacked horizontally.

Here is the HTML :

```
<core-card id="core_card" vertical layout >
  <paper-item label="Title 0" icon="keep" id="paper_item0" center horizontal layout>Description 0</paper-item>
  <paper-item label="Title 1" icon="keep" id="paper_item1" center horizontal layout>Description 1</paper-item>
  <paper-item label="Title 2" icon="keep" id="paper_item2" center horizontal layout>Description 2</paper-item>
</core-card>
```

For more information on layout attributes and flexbox : [see polymer documentation](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html)

Comment: Erwan, please review my comments above. Any suggestions?

Comment: @marcelino I think your confusion stems from understanding how layout attributes are applied. When you set `layout horizontal` on an element, it causes the element to lay out its _children_ horizontally. In Erwan's example, he's setting the contents of each card element to be laid out horizontally (of which there are none). To lay out the cards themselves horizontally, you need to specify `layout horizontal` on their container.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider when modifying polymer examples is to look at

https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html

What still trips me is the use o `start`, `center` and `end` instead of left center and right for both vertical and horizontal layout.